# Firefox & Chrome isn't launching

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, osx-yosemite, google-chrome-canary

I recently updated Xcode and the OS to 10.10.3.  Firefox, Firefox Dev Edition, Chrome, and Canary all stopped working.  They just bounce in the dock.  They do the same thing in safe mode. Only Safari is working.

I see this error message repeatedly in the console:

```
2015-04-28 09:16:43.161 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.watchdogd) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
2015-04-28 09:16:53.384 watchdogd[567]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(    wd_watchdog_open) - IOIteratorNext failed (kr=0)
2015-04-28 09:16:53.384 watchdogd[567]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(      wd_daemon_init) - could not initialize the hardware watchdog
2015-04-28 09:16:53.385 watchdogd[567]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(                main) - cannot initialize the watchdog service
```

What can I do to get my browsers working again?

update 1:

I deleted several plist items.  Things I found with google or mozilla in the title.  Then I repaired system permissions.  The message seems the same as when I repaired permissions 15 minutes ago:

```
Repairing permissions for “Untitled”
ACL found but not expected on “Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0”
Repaired “Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0”
User differs on “private/var/db/displaypolicyd”; should be 0; user is 244.
Group differs on “private/var/db/displaypolicyd”; should be 0; group is 244.
Repaired “private/var/db/displaypolicyd”
Permissions repair complete
```

update 2:
Apple had me create another admin user and test the browsers.  The problem is user specific not system wide.

Comment: Did you try to brute-forcly close the applications via the task manager? And then starting them back up again?

Comment: The Chrome part does NOT seem Mac specific  I can not get unstable (the equal to canary --I'm on Fedora Linux) fails to load even a new tab window

Comment: @Bas I can force close them.  They are still failing.  Repaired permissions and I am going to reboot.